# if and col_length syntax

Tags: mysql

Statement :

```
if col_length('memes', 'rating_test') is null 
    begin 
    alter table `memes` add column `rating_test` varchar(36) 
    end
```

Error message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` if col_length('memes', 'rating_test') is null begin alter table `memes` add colu ``' at line 1

Why is the above error message being generated?

Comment: The `IF` statement is listed in a section of MySQL manual called `Compound-Statement Syntax`, and it says: *This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the **body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events**.* I don't believe you can just write a standalone `IF` statement like that. You have to put such code in a procedure.

Comment: Col_length is not a mysql function is this question wrongly tagged?

Comment: You're using SQL Server syntax in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is not proper use this Syntax it should work.

```
    If Exists (Select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES Where  Table_Name = N'YourTableName')
BEGIN
    If(COL_LENGTH('[TableName]','ColumnName') is NULL)
    BEGIN
        Alter Table [TableName]
        Add ColumnName DataType(Size) NULL
    END
END
GO
```